# dlopen/dlclose execution environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, dlopen

I have a Linux process within multiple threads that uses dlopen/dlclose. Constructors of static objects are called from inside dlopen and destructors of static objects are called from dlclose.

What is about the threading environment in these cases, are multiple threads still running, is there a danger of constructors/destructors collisions on data with the other active threads?

Update:

In this case, I am a library developer, my question is what can I expect from applications using the library?  I would not expect direct calls to the library in question while dopen/dlclose are in progress but constructors/destructors may have data collisions.

Also, my question is not about calling dlopen/dlclose multiple times.

Say I have a static instance of a class that takes a mutex to access some shared data, should I take this mutex in the destructor called from dlclose as a part of a cleanup?

Comment: If you other execution threads running code from a shared library that one of the execution threads is dlclosing, you have more problems to worry about than just constructors and destructors.

Comment: If you call `dlopen` multiple times on the same shared lib, it will be loaded on the first call, and subsequent calls will increment reference count. Same for `dlclose`, but in reverse. So, the static ctors will be called once one the first `dlopen` call. And, static dtors will be called on the last call to `dlclose`.

Comment: According to [`dlopen(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html#ATTRIBUTES) man page both `dlopen` and `dlclose` are multi-thread-safe. Not sure why people are downvoting...